# upgrade 1.7.4 to django 1.8 south.db.mysql error, not using South

Tags: mysql, django

Trying to upgrade from 1.7.4 to 1.8 of django; however, when I runserver I now get

`There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.`

Error message and it doesn't work.  I don't have 'South' in my INSTALLED_APPS. and don't recall ever using south on this project. All my models are actually manually managed.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

[edit]
As you will see, i have lots of "upgrade" fixes to do, but still don't see why its failing on 'south' with I don't use it.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'bootstrap3',
    'towel',
    'email_registration',
    'visits',
    'django_markdown',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'LessonApp',
    'bootstrap_pagination',
    'django_tables2',
    'util',
    'memcache_admin',
    'twitter_feed',
    'cec_cms',
    'ckeditor',
    'filebrowser',
    'user_profile',
    'eztexting',
    'secure_file',
    'partboard',
)
```

traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:171: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  attrs["base_columns"] = SortedDict(parent_columns)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:193: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  attrs["base_columns"].update(SortedDict(cols))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/modelsinspector.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
  from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:174: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  extra = SortedDict()

/home/marc/PycharmProjects/CECLessonApp/ckeditor/widgets.py:10: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
  from django.forms.util import flatatt

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/memcache_admin/views.py:22: RemovedInDjango19Warning: 'get_cache' is deprecated in favor of 'caches'.
  mc_client = get_cache(SETTINGS['CACHE'])._cache

/home/marc/PycharmProjects/CECLessonApp/CECLessonApp/urls.py:18: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Default value of 'RedirectView.permanent' will change from True to False in Django 1.9. Set an explicit value to silence this warning.
  url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico')),

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:171: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  attrs["base_columns"] = SortedDict(parent_columns)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:193: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  attrs["base_columns"].update(SortedDict(cols))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/modelsinspector.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
  from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tables2/tables.py:174: RemovedInDjango19Warning: SortedDict is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
  extra = SortedDict()

/home/marc/PycharmProjects/CECLessonApp/ckeditor/widgets.py:10: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
  from django.forms.util import flatatt

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/memcache_admin/views.py:22: RemovedInDjango19Warning: 'get_cache' is deprecated in favor of 'caches'.
  mc_client = get_cache(SETTINGS['CACHE'])._cache

/home/marc/PycharmProjects/CECLessonApp/CECLessonApp/urls.py:18: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Default value of 'RedirectView.permanent' will change from True to False in Django 1.9. Set an explicit value to silence this warning.
  url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico')),

Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
visits.Visit.ip_address: (fields.W900) IPAddressField has been deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 1.9.
        HINT: Use GenericIPAddressField instead.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py:9: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import truncate_name

There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS
```

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and the complete traceback you are getting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought to leave my question as is, and show the answer I found here:

```
pip uninstall South
```

not sure why having the package south throws this kind of error as my project doesn't use it! but it appears to have solved my problem.

Comment: This worked for me, but it really doesn't seem like this should be the answer.

Comment: somehow this doesn't work for me. I continue to get the same error

Comment: did you also remove the south_migrations folders, etc? or perhaps another package is still refrencing it

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if your project has dependencies whose South migrations still live in the "migrations" folder, rather than the "south_migrations" folder

Comment: that's what i found on google, but i cleared out (deleted) all migrations folders (even from dependent packages)... unless some of the native django had migrations folders.  either way, the error states removing 'South' from installed packages should work (but didn't).

Comment: I tracked it by putting a breakpoint on the line in south that produces the exception message and found that south is still being imported by "migrations" (not "south_migrations") in a long forgotten dependency.  If you can do that, or hack south to give a you a stack trace on the production of that error, you should hopefully see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In `modules.py` just change:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    ...
    ip = models.IPAddressField(blank=True)
```

to

```
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=False)
```